# System disk to small for Windows upgrades - How can I extend it

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs

### I have a Windows mini-pc with a SSD system-disk.  It is to small for an upgrade I want to do now.  Is there some way I can extend it with external drives?

-It is not so much I can remove from it, and I have already moves some stuff off with Junction points

-The main issue is the upgrade process

Comment: How about get a bigger SSD, and system clone the disk over?

Comment: You could extend it to another drive using [striping](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/68572.aspx), but I don't think Windows doesn't support RAID with external drives.  Your best bet is to replace your SSD with a drive with more capacity.

Comment: @cybernard: Its a bit an overkill for an upgrade of a cheap Mini-PC.  Also they are not so easy to open.

Answer (score 0):

It may be impossible in your case, as I would recommend to get a new ssd but its not probably worth it in your situation.

Only things you can try: use system cleanup tool to remove temporary update files, old versions etc. Etc. Everything possible.

Check virtual memory amount - right click "my computer" or "this pc", properties, advanced system settings at left, tab called performance, find this virtual memory/swap, check how huge it is and make it down to 1000 mb.

Disable hiberation and delete the file by going to cmd in admin mode and typing: powercfg -h off

Move every music, video and image files to external drive.

These ways can give you even tens of gigabytes free space, if it would be enough for you :)